# How to connect my ModMic Uni (3.5 mm plug) to my MOTU M2 audio interface (6.35 mm jack)

Tags: microphone

The title says it all:

How do I connect my ModMic Uni (3.5 mm plug) to my MOTU M2 audio interface (6.35 mm jack)?

I'm very much a newbie when it comes to audio. I bought a 3.5 mm to 6.35 mm converter but it doesn't work. I'm assuming that it's made for headphones and not microphones. That said, since I'm unable to find a converter made for microphones, I'm assuming a flaw in my reasoning somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed was a Minijack to XLR Adapter with Power Convertor: http://www.rode.com/accessories/vxlrplus

Answer (score 1):

Most 3.5mm mics are 3v to 5v, the Motu is 12v to 48v.  You'll need a volt adapter to the down power the Motu, but the adapter may introduce more noise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it made me realize I didn't post any update here after I found the solution. The item I needed is this: http://www.rode.com/accessories/vxlrplus. It's indeed a voltage adapter, TIL!